# Animating labels in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is it possible to create some sort of animation for a label in Corona SDK? I want to make a text appear big then, the position will move after it comes up and shrinks? I don't want to use an image because the text on my label changes. If it is possible, can you please point me to the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this is what you are looking..?

```
local label = display.newText("Label_1",50,100,nil,20)

local function transition_3()
   label.text = "Label_3"
   transition.to(label,{time=1000,xScale=1,yScale=1})
end
local function transition_2()
   label.text = "Label_2"
   transition.to(label,{time=1000,x=label.x+50,y=label.y+50,onComplete=transition_3})
end
transition.to(label,{time=1000,xScale=1.5,yScale=1.5,onComplete=transition_2})
```

Keep coding........ :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the resizing part. If I understand this correctly, xScale and yScale would resize the text right? Right now, my text starts out really small and gets bigger. I'm trying to do the opposite, make the text appear big initially and shrink it. I tried making the scale for transition 1 to 1.5 and 1.0 for transition 3 but I end up with a very tiny text. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: just add "label:scale(1.5,1.5)" after the first line(that you creating the label)... :)

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured it out right after I posted this but completely forgot to remove  my post. Sorry and thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

What krs said -- basically, a text object is a display object just like an image. You can do just about anything to a text object that you can do to an image.